# Can't get AsyncFileUpload to work in update panel

Tags: asp.net

I have a user control with a updatepanel, script manager and a asyncfileupload control.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %> 
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server" ></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <cc1:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload2" runat="server" />
        <asp:LinkButton id="lbSubmitOrder" runat="server" title="Submit Order Request" class="btn_blue_dynamic_med"/>
    </ContentTemplate>      
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In my code behind:

```
 Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("~/temp/test.tmp")

 AsyncFileUpload2.SaveAs(path)
```

In my AsyncFileUpload2 object the filename is nothing.  I can't seem to get a refernce to the file that is supposed to be uploaded.

-Nate

**UPDATE**
I've added

```
Private Sub AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs) Handles AsyncFileUpload1.UploadedComplete
    If e.state = AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadState.Success Then
        '....'
    Else
        showErrorMessage(e)
    End If
End Sub
```

I can't hit a break point at the "if" statement after I choose a file.  I guess there is something wrong on my page with how ajax is working?  Not sure what it is though.

**FIXED!**
I was displaying the ajax upload box via a radio button with a visible=true/false div.  The answer told me that the control has to be there the page loads.  I took away the div and everything worked! I will now do the show/hide through jquery (which I should have done in the first place).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that the usercontrol with asyncfileupload control is not loaded asynchronously, for example via Response.Redirect("pageWithUploadControl").

Have you handled the FileUploadComplete Event and checked if AsyncFileUploadState is Success?

```
   Private Sub AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs) Handles AsyncFileUpload1.UploadedComplete
        If e.state = AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadState.Success Then
            '....'
        Else
            showErrorMessage(e)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub showErrorMessage(ByVal e As AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs)
        Dim message As String = String.Empty
        Select Case e.statusMessage
            Case AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload.Constants.Errors.EmptyContentLength
                message = "Empty content length!"
            Case AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload.Constants.Errors.FileNull
                message = "Fill NULL!"
            Case AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload.Constants.Errors.InputStreamNull
                message = "Input Stream NULL!"
            Case AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload.Constants.Errors.NoFileName
                message = "No File Name!"
            Case AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUpload.Constants.Errors.NoFiles
                message = "No Files!"
        End Select
        LblMessage.Text = message 
    End Sub
```

Try to change change the enctype of your form:

```
<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">
```

Comment: Not hitting that break point.  Does that mean I have a problem with my script manager?  I dont know how to debug from here...

Comment: @Nate: see my edit and try to change the enctype of the form.

Comment: sir, can you make a C# version of this script? I'm facing the same problem right now.

Comment: @BlackHatShadow: Use one of the online convertes, e.g. here: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/?batchId=cbeb9ca1-7cc7-4213-aad1-6ff7ad34fdbb

Answer (score 4):

Hi you can do it by using `OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUploadPDF_UploadedComplete"`
in .cs file add

```
protected void AsyncFileUploadPDF_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
        {
            if (AsyncFileUploadImage.HasFile)
            {
                Session["AsyncFileUploadPDF"] = AsyncFileUploadImage;
            }
        }
```

and you can get data from session where ever you want as I get on click event of button

```
protected void btnSaveParts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AsyncFileUploadPDF = (AsyncFileUpload)Session["AsyncFileUploadPDF"];
            PdfFileName = AsyncFileUploadPDF.FileName;         
        }
```

Comment: This is really helpful.^_^

Comment: Where is the file?? How to save the file?

Answer (score 3):

In case this helps someone, I fixed my problem by adding the following to the form tag:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, read and tried countless posts on how to fix it (obviously a lot of people are having this issue) but nothing worked. Until I replaced the `ScriptManager` with the `ToolkitScriptManager`

Change:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server" ></asp:ScriptManager>
```

with:

```
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="Server" />
```

I am not sure if this is requirement on the latest tool kit (December 2013), but it worked for me. Hopefully it will help someone else too.