# can AsyncFileUpload works with UpdatePanel?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

can `AsyncFileUpload` works with `UpdatePanel`? I know that `FileUpload` can not work with `UpdatePanel`

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1489399.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can. See: [Can't get AsyncFileUpload to work in update panel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5423911/532498)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, You can do that however make you always **load `AsyncFileUpload` Or the panel containing `AsyncFileUpload` control in Page Load. NEVER do `Visible="false"` for `AsyncFileUpload` or it's parent container.**

For visibility control use `webcontrol.style.Add("visibility","hidden")` or
`webcontrol.style.Add("visibility","visible")` to hide / unhide .

Secondly make sure to use Session and NOT `ViewState` to store any of your data in all server side events fired by this `AsyncFileUpload`

we spent lot of hours doing trial and error but this will work 100% for IE 7,8,9 and FF and chrome. Hope it saves nightmare to many out there!!!

Comment: A million times thank you for the suggestion about visibility control. I ran into the same issue!

Comment: Thanks a lot. If I cannot use the viewstate, how can I update a label text inside FileUploadComplete event?

Answer (score 2):

An easy workaround is to add another AsyncFileUpload outside the UpdatePanel, enclosed within a hidden div. This will ensure all necessary client side wiring is conducted at page load:

```
...
</UpdatePanel>


<div style="display: none;">
  <cc1:AsyncFileUpload ID="dummy" runat="sever" />
</div>
```