# AjaxControlToolkit Asynch File Uploader not working correctly

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an AsynchFileUpload on my page and for some reason when I try to use it to save the file to the server it falls.

The control will allow me to select a file locally and it displays the local file path in its text box, BUT when I then click a button on my page which I am going to be using to submit all details then upload the page everything goes wrong and I get a Null Ref Exception from the AsynchFileUploader.

My uploader is fairly basic and looks like:

```
   <cc1:AsyncFileUpload runat="server" 
                                  ID="AsyncFileUpload2" 
                                  Enabled="true" 
                                  Visible="true"/>
```

The uploader is within a tab container / tab panel / content template / update panel with the update mode set to conditional.  Im fairly new to ASP so im not sure if the controls containing the uploader could be causing the problem.

Then in my code i have:

```
 Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUpload2.FileName)

        Dim comments As String = SpellTextBox1.Text


        Dim NewDirectory As String = Server.MapPath("~/Helpdesk/UploadedFiles/" + TicketID.ToString())

        Try



           'Check if directory exists
           If Not Directory.Exists(NewDirectory) Then

              ' Create the directory.
              Directory.CreateDirectory(NewDirectory)

           End If

           AsyncFileUpload2.SaveAs(NewDirectory + "\" + filename)

        Catch _ex As IOException
           'Silently error for now
           'Response.Write(_ex.Message)

        End Try
```

It seems that the filename is being lost somewhere after the button is clicked, or just never stored

Comment: Have a look at my answer on a similar question and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423911/cant-get-asyncfileupload-to-work-in-update-panel/5423992#5423992

Comment: Thanks I had seen that one before, I think im a bit confused by how this control works though as I thought the UploadedComplete event wouldnt fire till I actually upload a file, since I havent specified a filepath or called the AsyncFileUpload2.SaveAs() method yet I wasnt expecting the uploadedcomplete event to be firing. Does the file get uploaded as soon as the user selects it?

Comment: I think you are mixing uploading to server and saving on server. When the user has selected the file on his PC, it'll be sent to server immediately. In UploadedComplete you can then decide if the mime-type is correct or whatelse and finally you can save it physically somewhere on the server.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I was making the incorrect assumption that the control was just allowing me to select a file on the client and that the upload & save would both be done at the same time when I called the save method which obviously isnt the case here. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing:

```
Private Sub AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs) Handles AsyncFileUpload1.UploadedComplete
      If e.State = AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadState.Success Then

         Dim ticketID As String = Request.QueryString("ID").ToString()
         Dim filename As String = e.FileName

         Dim temp() As String = filename.Split("\")
         filename = temp(temp.Length - 1)


         Dim NewDirectory As String = Server.MapPath("~/Helpdesk/UploadedFiles/" + ticketID + "/")

         'Check if directory exists
         If Not Directory.Exists(NewDirectory) Then

            ' Create the directory.
            Directory.CreateDirectory(NewDirectory)

         End If

         ' Save the file on the server
         AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(NewDirectory + filename)

         'Now put the file details in the database
         dbSaveFile(ticketID, filename, "UploadedFiles/" + ticketID + "/" + filename, "")

         'Raise some kind of notification informing the user that this has been sucessfull



         'And rebind the control
         ' Get Event Details and populate text fields
         Dim dsFiles As DataSet = dbGetFiles(ticketID)

         If dsFiles Is Nothing Then
            ' No need to error here if we have no files
         Else
            gvFiles.DataSource = dbGetFiles(ticketID)
            gvFiles.DataBind()

         End If

      Else
         ' Do nothing
      End If
   End Sub
```