# Ajax Asynchronous file upload issue

Tags: asp.net, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't get AsyncFileUpload to work in update panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423911/cant-get-asyncfileupload-to-work-in-update-panel)

In Ajax, there is an issue with asynchronous file upload control if when we use in update panel. When we use update panel control then it does not work.

Below is my code.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %> 
    <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server" ></cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <cc1:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload2" runat="server" />
            <asp:LinkButton id="lbSubmitOrder" runat="server" title="Submit Order Request" class="btn_blue_dynamic_med"/>
        </ContentTemplate>      
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When we use Asynchronous file uploads control within ajax update panel then it does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are repeating that it "does not work", but can you be more concrete? Here is a step-by-step guide: http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2009/10/01/fileupload-in-updatepanel-asp.net-like-gmail.aspx
Maybe [my answer on a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423911/cant-get-asyncfileupload-to-work-in-update-panel/5423992#5423992) will help.